# How to move the view up on button click

Tags: iphone, uibutton

When i click on button it shows up the picker view and hide the button,User have no idea what's going on behind the picker view.

Any Solution:-

Like we have solution for textfield, the view goes up on selection of textfield with animateTextField.

Comment: Your search arround a bit.

Comment: inside button click method u can add

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-10,320,400);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: Thanks..... Aman and bhuXan it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method animate view upward to move the view upward and can move the view downward using the methods below :

```
    -(void)animateViewUpward
     {
       [UIView beginAnimations: @"upView" context: nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];
       [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
       self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-110, 320,460);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
     }

   -(void)animateViewDownward
    {
       [UIView beginAnimations: @"downView" context: nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];
       [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
       self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320,460);
       [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click use animations

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                    animations:^{ 
                        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-30,320,400);
                    } 
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        ;
                    }];
```

And when you press done or cancel of toolbar OR you are done with picker selection

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                    animations:^{ 
                        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,400);
                    } 
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        ;
                    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the UIKeyboardScrollView on view. It will move up the components whenever you will click the button or anything else.